# Blender materials and animating problems

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm new here but I'll jump right into it.

I am trying to animate a character in blender, I use nodes for materials. The model ends up completely black. Then sometimes when I switch between textures and materials or close and open blender the materials fix themselves. Also when I animate it would just crash and close. Another thing that happened is, it would only render 1 character in a scene instead of 2. All items in the render layers were visible. Is my computer just not able to handle blender? I have a Nvidia GTX graphics card.

Comment: Can you add a picture of you material node setup?

Comment: @Sazerac Here you are :)   https://www.deviantart.com/tommy-thedirtden/art/nodes-780176471?ga_submit_new=10%3A1546896369

Comment: heres some specs   Name NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
Memory 8GB  Processor AMD FX(tm)-4300 Quad Core Processor 3.80GHz

Comment: Your nodes look fine, although you may want a UV map. Have you tried updating drivers for your GPU?

Comment: @Sazerac There were updates for the driver.